# Арина-божий-одуванчик

Tags: дефис

Можете, сэры вы да пэры, мне сказать, как правильно таки написать?

1. Арина-божий-одуванчик, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?
2. Арина божий-одуванчик, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?
3. Арина божий одуванчик, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?

Я думаю, как кот, что 1-й вариант прав.

Comment: Извините, я ошибся в предыдущем (удаленном) комментарии

Comment: Какой кот?.....

Comment: Еще вариант: *Арина, божий одуванчик*.

Comment: Вариант может быть прав?

Comment: "сэры Вы да пары" мне кажется, вы имели в виду пэры, а не пары.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, мистер-пэр.

Comment: "Божий одуванчик" о старых людях. Эта Арина точно старая? https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/Божий_одуванчик

Answer (score 2):

Я предложу **интонационное решение**. Ну и пользуясь случаем, скажу несколько слов о роли интонации при выборе знаков препинания, а вернее **процитирую книгу**: Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И.. Современный русский язык: Учебник / Под редакцией Н.С. Валгиной. - 6-е изд., перераб. и доп. Москва: Логос,2002.  528 с.. 2002

«Пунктуация связана с интонацией. Однако и в этом случае нет прямой зависимости первой от второй: обе служат средствами выражения **смысла речи**, причем интонация выполняет эту функцию **в устной речи**, а пунктуация – в речи письменной».

Итак, главное – это смысл, а интонация и пунктуация практически напрямую соотносятся между собой, кроме некоторых исключений. Таким образом, **запись по слуху** вполне возможна.

**Решение задачи**

Смысл сказанного понятен; рассмотрим три  **интонационных варианта** относительно пауз и ударений.

**Вариант 1.**  Оценочное обращение

***АрИна, // божий одувАнчик**, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?*

Две грамматические (подчеркнутые) паузы, два ударения.

**Вариант 2.** Обращение по прозвищу

***АрИна — // божий одуванчик**, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?*

Первая пауза произносительная, одно ударение.

**Вариант 3.** Обращение по прозвищу

***Арина божий одувАнчик**, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?*

Одна пауза, одно ударение, слитное произношение.**

**P.S.** А что же **первый вариант**: Арина-божий-одуванчик, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?

Правилами такая запись не нормируется, да и непонятно, как читается.
Это одно **фонетическое слово** (слитное произношение), но там делается два ударения, **основное и вспомогательное.** Если произнести АрИна (основное ударение), то это будет второй вариант, а если произнести одувАнчик, то это будет третий вариант, так что ничего нового не получится.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса** (три формы записи)

"Вот тебе двести рублей». Старичок, **божий одуванчик**, руки мне целовал.

Он метнулся в палисадник подобно буре – и чуть не сшиб с ног **старушку – божий одуванчик**, вышедшую на крылечко и уже готовую запереть дверь.

Там квартировал именно Ленин, а не какой-нибудь **француз божий одуванчик**.

**Вывод**

Таким образом, **мы имеем**: три формы записи, разрешенные правилами, три вида интонации и три разных смысловых оттенка. Есть из чего выбрать.

Comment: Мне нравится вариант без знака. Вам надо было больше уделить ему внимания, пообосновывать. Под ответом с претензией к нему отстаиваю вашу позицию и обосновываю этот вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, я читала. Но пока у меня нет желания подробно раскрывать эту тему... Отвечу, вероятно, чуть позже.

Comment: Там комментарий добавлен сегодня, видели? Вот он прямо развеивает туман и расставляет всё по местам.

Comment: Мне сложно следить за ходом всей дискуссии, она ведется не в моем формате. Поэтому надо время, чтобы разобраться. У меня ведь свободное мышление, да? И ответ будет соответствующий.

Comment: Просто нажимаете "Отслеживать", чтобы не следить самостоятельно. Не мышление, поведение, это другое. Ваша чрезмерная свобода даёт и новаторство. Такая свобода негативна.

Comment: Это ваша точка зрения. Свободному мышлению нужно свободное поведение, как содержанию нужна форма для его выражения. Как вас еще расшевелить и взбодрить. Это всего лишь риторические приемы, ага?  И поведение у меня всегда в рамках правил, уважительное по отношению к собеседнику и доброжелательное, не правда ли? )) И пока до свидания.

Comment: Мыслить надо свободно, но не выходить за рамки нормального и правильного. Эту свободу имею в виду. Из-за чрезмерной свободы часто выходите. Нужна осторожность, как в тех ваших статьях.

Comment: Нет, не правда. Вы часто на личности переходили. Не раз делал вам замечание. Ну под поведением имею в виду не это, а написание ответов, не очень удачное слово подобрал. Но сейчас ответы норм, без глупостей, а до этого (недавно) чуть ли не каждый приходилось комментировать.

Comment: Да я вообще здесь тише воды и ниже травы по сравнению с другими, в том числе с вами))  Кто говорил,что любит резкости, а? А я вот не люблю.

Comment: Ну, мои резкости правила не нарушают :) На личности не перехожу.

Comment: Переходите, переходите... А на моей личности вообще, так сказать, "оттоптались" вволю…

Comment: Вам кажется... Оценка ответов — это не оценка личности :)

Comment: Ну и вам все кажется... Ну что, ничья?

Comment: Когда мне кажется, говорю, что мне кажется. Иначе говорю истину :) Ну вы перестали переходить, после тех замечаний. Хотя вот вчера опять написали то, что нельзя по правилам. Но быстро удалили.

Comment: Ничего не помню... И замечания тоже. Я их не замечаю, наверное))  И все, я ушла.

Answer (score 1):

Когда определяемое слово и приложение равноправны, как в сочетаниях: офицер-ракетчик, художник-самоучка, соседка-педагог, то ставится дефис, если определяемое слово и приложение состоят из одного слова, а если определяемое слово и приложение состоят из двух и более слов, как в сочетаниях: старшего лейтенанта — артиллериста, участников войны — инвалидов, у научного сотрудника — космонавта, то ставится тире. Второй вариант подходит для сочетания **Арина – божий одуванчик**, поэтому ставится тире. [Вот этот пункт в справочнике Лопатина (пункт 1).](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php)

Но это если Арина – божий одуванчик – это прозвище из какой-нибудь сказки, как Пеппи – длинный чулок. Есть ещё один вариант, где идёт серия обращений, где второе обращение положительно окрашенное – ‟Арина, божий одуванчик, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой”. В таком случае сочетание ‟божий одуванчик” обособляется запятыми.

Comment: Понимаю, но как-то не очень. Тире — когда единое понятие, а здесь оценочное.

Comment: По-моему, идеально подходит, потому что это единое прозвище.

Comment: Здесь не прозвище, а оценка, например: *самолёт-красавец* (из справочника).

Comment: Нет, здесь тоже прозвище, как Пеппи – длинный чулок. Вот Пеппи – длинный чулок подходит меньше, потому что никто не назовёт её длинный чулок, даже метафорически.

Comment: Ну чего прозвище? Это характеристика. https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/Божий_одуванчик

Comment: Здесь везде в контексте люди обращаются к ней, как Арина – божий одуванчик. Так к ней обращаются. К ней обращаются не по слову Арина, а по слову Арина – божий одуванчик. Это из сказки или из чего-то подобного.

Comment: А мне кажется, что так назвали для прикола, чтобы сказать, что она добрая и безобидная.

Comment: Есть три вида отношений определяемого слова и приложения: равноправные, как соседка-педагог; с приложение-пояснением, как в соседка, педагог; а также род-вид отношения, как гриб лисичка. Тут подходит только один. Но так же подходит вариант, где идёт серия обращений, а второе обращение окрашенное, тогда тут будет обособление запятыми – Алина, божий одуванчик, а вы пришли...

Comment: В принципе такой вариант тоже подходит. Добавлю его в ответ.

Comment: Это про написание. Но они не равноправные. *Соседка какая? Педагог.* Приложения выполняют определительную функцию. Связь подчинительная. Равноправные в: *правда-истина, купля-продажа* (но здесь уже не приложения).

Comment: Может быть два варианта.

Comment: Это о чём? О том, что в ответе?

Comment: С соседка-педагог. Может быть дефис и обособление запятыми.

Comment: Но зачем рассматривать случаи, когда есть пауза? Это и так понятно. Спрашивается про то, где нет отступления.

Comment: Там ставится дефис, а остальное мне неинтересно.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                Расскажу я всё, как было со мной, 

                                Как лечили ОТ СВОБОДЫ МЕНЯ...

                     (Из популярной песни с некоторой доработкой)
```

**Цитата из комментария участника форума**: *Дайте ссылку **на правило**, разрешающее эту третью форму записи. Если вы не приведёте ссылку, то я бы попросил вас **удалить ваш ответ.***

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ АНАЛИЗ** для варианта с раздельным написанием:

***Арина божий одуванчик**, а Вы домой пришли являясь-таки мокрой?*

1. Я предполагаю, что это **обращение** к девочке, шутливое и часто повторяемое, так что в такой записи оно выглядит **как прозвище** (дети ведь тоже цветы жизни))

Словосочетание (как прозвище)  строится на основе имени, к которому добавлено **определение**.

2. Насколько корректна такая запись и разрешена ли она **правилами?**

Вполне себе корректна, достаточно заглянуть в правила Розенталя: ***Владимир Красное Солнышко, Ричард Львиное Сердце.***

Это прозвища, построенные **по такому же образцу**: имя и характерный признак лица.

Даже ссылку можно не давать, но все-таки вот она: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=15#pp15

3. А что там **с произношением**?  В предложении обращение будет оформлено как отдельная **фраза** с одним **фразовым ударением**. Оно ставится в конце фразы или смещено на первое слово: ***Арина божий одувАнчик. АрИна божий одуванчик.***

И даже про дефисы не пришлось рассказывать…))

**P.S.** Для чего мы учим правила?

Думаю, что не для того, чтобы носить с собой справочник и цитировать его при необходимости. Правила должны стать **основой нашего **СВОБОДНОГО** мировоззрения**, чтобы в любой момент мы могли бы (без особых размышлений) ответить на подобный вопрос.

```
               Грузный корабль, капитан настороженный,
               Знающий мир по вращению глобуса,
               Энергетически предрасположены
               Сгинуть в безвестности вечного хроноса!

               https://stihi.ru/2022/04/27/6838
```